# javascript json class onclick hide another json class

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I don't understand why it is important to *view* or see when its just the logic I'm looking for.. However I just added the index.html file that can make things show... I hope it helps anyone !

what I'm trying to achieve is..

```
var small  = document.getElementsByClassName("small");
var story = document.getElementsByClassName("story");
small.onclick = function() { story.style.display = "block"; }
```

I'm aware they should be done for loop and added as [i] in the end of both vars... 
But how can i relate each small to story when they're both same id...

How can I tell

```
document.getElementsByClassName("small")[0];
```

to show

```
document.getElementsByClassName("story")[0];
```

when I have Multiple Class Values...
Thought about adding (this) in onclick() html tag but im not experienced enough....

Here's the Main Code:

```js
  var div   = document.getElementById("content");
 var ajax  = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open('GET', 'rss.json', true);
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
  {
   var items = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
   var output = '<ul class="main">';
  
   for(var key in items)
   {
    output += '<li class="IDZ"><b><pre>' + items[key].IDZ + '</b></pre></li>'; 
    output += '<li class="topic"><h1><u>' + items[key].topic + '</u></h1></li>'; 
    output += '<li id="" class="small"><a href="#"  >' + items[key].small + '</a></li><br>';
    output += '<li class="story">' + items[key].story + '</li><br>';
    output += '<li class="media"><img src='+items[key].media+'>' + '</li>'; 
    output += '<hr>';
   }

   output += '</ul>';
   div.innerHTML = output;
  }
 }
 ajax.send(null);
```

rss.json file

```js
{
 "rss1":
 {
  "IDZ"  : 1,
  "topic" : "Topic One",
  "small" : "A Brief Intro about this story.",
  "story" : "Main Story starts when A B C were born to become all good and tidy for the little things that made IDZ : 1 A Story",
  "media" : "images/IDZ1.jpg"
 },

 "rss2":
 {
  "IDZ"  : 2,
  "topic" : "Topic 2",
  "small" : "A Brief Intro about another story.",
  "story" : "Main Story starts when A B C were born to become all good and tidy for the little things that made IDZ : 2 A Story",
  "media" : "images/IDZ2.jpg"
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html encoding="utf-8" >
 <head>
  <title>json parser</title>
  <style>
   /*  { border: 0; margin:0; padding: 0;} */
   
   body    { position: relative; }
   ul     { }
   li        { list-style-type: none; font-size:1em;}
   a        { text-decoration: none; }
   a:visited { color: #f22; }
   .id    { text-align: center; }


  </style>
  
  <script>
   document.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
    if(document.readyState == "complete")
    {
     var loadscript  = document.getElementById("content");
     var script   = document.createElement("script");
     script.type   = "text/javascript";
     script.src   = "script.js";
     loadscript.appendChild(script);  
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="content">

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet produces no output...

Comment: apologies aug,
Just added the JSON file.

Comment: It still produces no output.

Comment: Don't embed HTML in JavaScript, use a template engine like Handlebars instead.  Building HTML in JavaScript strings creates code that is very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "data" attribute to store the key and also include the key in the id as follows:

```
for(var key in items)
{
    output += '<li id="" data-key="'+ key +'" class="small"><a href="#"  >' + items[key].small + '</a></li><br>';
    output += '<li class="story" id="story_key_'+ key +'">' + items[key].story + '</li><br>';

}

small.onclick = function(elem) 
{ 
    story.style.display = "block"; 

    var storyKey = elem.dataset.key;
    var storyItem = document.getElementById("story_key_" + storyKey);
}
```

(Note: this is only an idea, this code isn't working code)